# python - code works fine on Linux but crashes on OSX

Tags: python, linux, macos, http, ssl

I'm running on OSX Mavericks and have python 3.3.3 installed.

```
Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 16 2013, 23:39:35)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin)
```

I'm trying to run this (unfinished) code (a simple HTTPS GET and POST with cookies), but it crashes with an unknown error:

```
import urllib.request as rqst
import re
import http.cookiejar

def LoginICorsi():
        loginUrl = "https://www2.icorsi.ch/auth/shibboleth/" 
        rqst.install_opener(rqst.build_opener(rqst.HTTPCookieProcessor(http.cookiejar.CookieJar())))
        pageBytes = rqst.urlopen(loginUrl)

        pageString = pageBytes.read().decode("utf-8")

        action = re.findall(r'action="([^"]*)', pageString)[0]

        loginPostUrl = "https://wayf.switch.ch" + action
        loginPostUrl = loginPostUrl.replace("&amp;", "&")

        print("Posting USI to "+loginPostUrl)
        postDATA = "user_idp=https://login2.usi.ch/idp/shibboleth".encode("utf-8")
        usiLoginRequest = rqst.Request(loginPostUrl)
        usiLoginRequest.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        usiLoginUrl = rqst.urlopen(usiLoginRequest, data=postDATA)
        usiLoginResult = usiLoginUrl.read().decode("utf-8")
        print(usiLoginResult)
```

The problem is that this code works on Ubuntu

```
Python 3.3.3 (default, Nov 20 2013, 00:22:18)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
```

so I suppose the code is correct.

Moreover, the code worked on my Mac when I set the system proxy for HTTPS to a proxy with Fiddler.

This is the traceback [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PXk9PLcP).

What am I missing? Does this have something to do with OSX, python, the HTTPS server or just my mac?
The problem arises when handshaking with the server, but I don't why it works on Linux.

Comment: How did you install Python 3.3.3 on your Mac? A binary installer (if so the one from python.org, or otherwise), or a source build (if so, Homebrew, MacPorts, or by hand)? The looks like a problem with the `ssl` module, and that's very easy to get if you, e.g., build using a recipe designed around OS X 10.8's OpenSSL but on a machine that actually has OS X 10.9.

Comment: I downloaded the binary installer, http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.3/python-3.3.3-macosx10.6.dmg

Answer (score 0):

Highly, highly recommend you migrate away from urllibs and onto python requests module.

Seriously, it's worth the 5 minutes to easy_install/pip and port your code. It will handle most SSL issues a lot more graceful and a lot less painful.

Comment: I was thinking about using an external module, but I would have really preferred to stay with python native modules...
Thanks for the reply, I'll try with python-requests and let you know.

Comment: I understand wanting to stay within the std lib, but request is SO worth it. Seriously.

Comment: There are lots of things requests is better at (including some of the things the OP is doing the hard way, like cookies). But basic SSL negotiation is not one of them. It uses the `ssl` module the same way `urllib` does.

Comment: If SSL becomes an issue, but you can safely ignore it, requests gives you the option to `verify=False`, For instance, if you trust the certificate, but your certificate store is acting up, you can handle that gracefully with requests, with urllibs that's a major pain.

Comment: I uninstalled python and reinstalled python 3.3.2 with MacPorts, and now everything works fine... I guess I'll stick with my code for now, but thank you anyways!